# Python, Multiprocessing, Pydev Console

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pydev

How do I use multiprocessing with a Pydev console (i.e. I run it by pressing CTRL+ALT+ENTER).

My script is

```
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(q):
    return q*q    

if __name__=='__main__':
    with Pool( processes=4 ) as pool:
        print( pool.map(f, np.arange(10)))
```

It will run if run it normally by pressing F9.

But if I run it in console mode I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
```

How do I get this to work in console mode, or do I need to use a different parallel processing tool?

Answer (score 1):

This note from the multiprocessing docs seems relevant:

Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some examples, such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in the interactive interpreter.